# Android WebView setInitialScale causes text overflow (but if I tap twice text, it is redrawn within screen width)

Tags: android, html, webview, overflow, zooming

Say, I have the following instruction in my code:

```
webView.setInitialScale(160);
```

before loading a local HTMl file.
After page loading I see that text is bigger than default as expected, but there is overflow and horizontal scrolling is enabled.
If I tap twice on text it is reflowed and stays within the screen width; no scrolling needed now.
I need that the text is correctly flowed without overflow already at loading time, without no need of tapping.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code

```
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
```

Comment: Sorry, my app doesn't feature setInitialScale anymore so I cannot test your suggestion.